# Recursively searching binary tree issue

Tags: java, search, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have written the below code for recursively searching binary tree .
Even though my system.out statement is getting executed , the return statement is not returning out of entire recursion and thus this method not returning true.

Can anyone suggest how can I return out of entire recursion.?

```
public static boolean isElementinTree(int num, BinaryTreeNode root) 
{
    if (root != null)
    {
        int rootVal = root.getData();
        BinaryTreeNode left = root.getLeft();
        BinaryTreeNode right = root.getRight();
        if (left != null)
        {
            isElementinTree(num,left);

        }
        if (right != null)
        {
            isElementinTree(num,right);
        }
        if (num == rootVal)
        {
            System.out.println("------ MATCH -----");               
            return true;
        }           
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you should first check if the data in the node matches and only if it doesn't, you should move to the left or to the right subtree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
if (left != null)
{
    isElementinTree(num,left);

}
if (right != null)
{
    isElementinTree(num,right);
}
```

You're *calling* the method in those cases - but ignoring the result. I suspect you just want to change each of those to return immediately if it's found:

```
if (left != null && isElementinTree(num, left))
{
    return true;
}
if (right != null && isElementinTree(num, right))
{
    return true;
}
```

Or to make the whole thing more declarative, you can do it more simply:

```
public static boolean isElementinTree(int num, BinaryTreeNode root) 
{
    return root != null && (root.getData() == num ||
                            isElementInTree(num, root.getLeft()) ||
                            isElementInTree(num, root.getRight()));
}
```

It's fine to call `isElementInTree` with a null second argument, as you're already protecting against that with the first part.

Comment: that would never return `true` for elements in the right half of the tree

Comment: That would only search the first branch, or am I missing something?

Comment: @pcalcao: See my second edit. The whole body collapsed to three lines :)

Comment: Nice, you have my upvote. Concise and doesn't sacrifice too much readability.

Comment: I'd say the three line version is _more_ readable as it captures the essence of the algorithm precisely - the value you are looking for is in the tree if it matches the root node, or is in the left subtree, or is in the right subtree.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Exactly. Declarative expressions tend to be more readable, IMO :)

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with a simple solution like this:

```
public static boolean isElementinTree(int num, BinaryTreeNode root)
{
    return root != null &&                           //The tree is non-null
           (num == root.getData() ||                 //We have num in this node OR
            isElementInTree(num, root.getLeft()) ||  //We have num in left subtree OR
            isElementInTree(num, root.getRight()) ); //We have num in right subtree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value is in one of the branches, and save that result.

Initialize a variable `boolean found = false;`.

When you do the recursive call, you need to do something like:

```
found = isElementinTree(num,left)
```

same thing for the right side.

At the end, instead of returning false, check if the value was found on a branch, simply `return found;`

Also, first check if the number you are looking for isn't on the Node itself, instead of searching each branch first. Simply switch the order of the if's.

Answer (score 0):

If you do find the element you're looking for in the left or right subtrees you need to return this fact back up to the caller:

```
    if (left != null)
    {
        if(isElementinTree(num,left)) return true;
    }
    if (right != null)
    {
        if(isElementinTree(num,right)) return true;
    }
```

Only if you find it in none of the left tree, right tree and current node do you eventually fall through to the final `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion solution:

```
boolean isElementinTree (int num, BinaryTreeNode root)
{
  if(root == null)
   return false;

  if(root.value == num)
   return true;

  boolean n1 = isElementinTree(num,root.getLeft());
  boolean n2 = isElementinTree(num,root.getRight());

  return n1 ? n1 : n2;

}
```